How to get the standard result of test dataset of ImageNet2012?
I have implemented a hardware accecleartor of ViT by using some linear-approximatelly method, and I want to test the accuracy on test dataset of ImageNet.
When I have downloaded the dataset(there are 10000 pictures in test dataset and 50000 val dataset), there is only the standard result txt for val dataset.
How can I get the standard label txt for teste dataset?
